# How to fetch HKMetadataKeySwimmingStrokeStyle from Healthkit API

Tags: ios, healthkit

How to fetch [HKMetadataKeySwimmingStrokeStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkmetadatakeyswimmingstrokestyle?language=objc) from HealthKit Api

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of calls for setting up predicates based on metadatakeys.
For example;

```
predicateForObjects(withMetadataKey key: String) -> NSPredicate
predicateForObjects(withMetadataKey key: String, allowedValues: [Any]) -> NSPredicate
```

Which you can use on sample queries, for example. But if you are not searching on a key, the metadata is returned in any sample query. So if you search for swimming strokes, if the metadata is available, it will be included in the returned record.

For example, in a sample workout query result I get;

```
 <HKWorkout> (41)  B20FF16B-CE3C-4989-9390-0F71646B7DC7 "Health" (12.4), "iPhone7,1" (12.4)metadata: {
HKWasUserEntered = 1;
} (2019-08-22 13:22:00 -0700 - 2019-08-22 14:22:00 -0700)
```

and you can see the metadata for 'was user entered'.